How to run Spring Boot backend and Angular frontend separately in a JHipster project?
I am working on a JHipster project that uses Spring Boot for the backend and Angular for the frontend. I want to run the backend and frontend separately on different ports to facilitate development and debugging.
Here's what I've tried so far:
For the backend: I use ./mvnw to start the Spring Boot application on port 8080, and it works as expected.
For the frontend: I use npm start to start the Angular development server on port 4200. However, when I open the frontend in the browser, I get a blank page.
How can I resolve the blank page issue when running the Angular frontend separately?
Backend: Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE
Frontend: Angular 12
JHipster: Version 5.4.1

Watch the dev console in the browser when you try to hit the angular app.
Hopefully, error messages there will be helpful.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
